# Need help with Circular Linked List in Java!

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, circular-list

yes this is one of my homework projects - to implement a Circular Linked List based on Singly Linked List. It's a pretty simple and the code is easy to read. All my attributes are public to avoid *getters* and *setters* and private business. For the purposes of this project *public* will suffice.

I initialized my **nItems** counter (# of items in the list) and Link head right in the attribute field, but I will change it later by initializing it inside of the constructor.

My **step()** method doesn't seem to work at all. My compiler just freezes for a moment and then nothing shows up. This is how step() method should work if I call it 4 times:

```
List: 40 80 30 20 10 70 50 
List: 80 30 20 10 70 50 40 
List: 30 20 10 70 50 40 80 
List: 20 10 70 50 40 80 30
```

**Find()** method works fine, that is as long as the value we are searching for is inside the Linked List. If it's not, it will keep on going forever. If this is my list, this what happens to **find()** method if you search for a value that isn't there (I debugged it step by step):

```
70 60 50 40 30 20 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10...and 10 forever
```

**Cause:** If they key value we are searching for isn't there, it will never get out from the while loop, hence forever repeating *current = current.next*.

```
while(current.dData != key) {
current = current.next;
```

My delete method says it deleted value 60 just as I wanted to, but this what I get:

```
Deleted link with key 60
70 60 40 30 20 10       // lie! it deletes 50 instead of 60
```

Please also take a look at my display() and my insert() methods. They look fine to me, but I could be wrong and it could be the source of all problems I am having with find() and delete() methods.

Thank you so much in advance!!!

```
class Link {
    public int dData;
    public Link next;

    public Link(int dd) {
        dData = dd;
    }

    public void displayLink() {
        System.out.print(dData + " ");
    }
}

class CircList {
    public Link head = null;
    int nItems = 0;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (nItems == 0);
    }
    // INSERT
    public void insert(int key) { 

        Link current = new Link(key);
        if(isEmpty())
            head = current;

        current.next = head;
        head = current;
        nItems++;
    }
    // STEP
    public void step() {
        Link current = head;
        do {
            current = current.next;
        } while(current != head);
    }
    // FIND
    public Link find (int key) {
        Link current = head;
        while(current.dData != key) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        return current;
    }
     // DELETE
    public Link delete(int key) {
    Link current = head;
    while(current.dData != key) {
        current = current.next;
    }
    if(current == head)
        head = head.next;
    else {
        current.next = current.next.next;
        nItems--;
    }
    return current;
}
    // DISPLAY
    public void displayList() {
        Link current = head; // start at beginning
        int counter = nItems;
        while(true) {
            if(counter != 0) {
                current.displayLink();
                current = current.next; // move to next link
                counter--;
            }
            else 
                break;
        }
    }
}

class CircListApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Link f, d;
    CircList theList = new CircList();


    theList.insert(10);      // insert items
    theList.insert(20);
    theList.insert(30);
    theList.insert(40);
    theList.insert(50);
    theList.insert(60);
    theList.insert(70);

    //System.out.println(theList.nItems + " ");
    theList.displayList();              // display list

    System.out.println("");

    f = theList.find(30);               // find item
    if( f != null)
       System.out.println("Found link with key " + f.dData);
    else
       System.out.println("Can't find link with key 30");

//    theList.step();

//
//    System.out.println("Inserting link with key 80");
//    theList.insert(80);
//    theList.displayList();              // display list
//
    d = theList.delete(60);             // delete item

    if( d != null )
       System.out.println("Deleted link with key " + d.dData);
    else
       System.out.println("Can't delete link with key 60");
    theList.displayList();              // display list
//
//    f = theList.find(99);               // find item
//    if( f != null)
//       System.out.println("Found link with key " + f.dData);
//    else
//       System.out.println("Can't find link with key 99" );
//    theList.displayList();              // display list
//
//    d = theList.delete(13);             // delete item
//    if( d != null )
//       System.out.println("Deleted link with key " + d.dData);
//    else
//       System.out.println("Can't delete link with key 13");
//    theList.displayList();              // display list
//
//    System.out.println("Stepping through list");
//    for(int j=0; j<theList.getSize; j++)
//       {
//       theList.step();
//       theList.displayList();
//       }
//
//    System.out.println("Will delete and step one by one");
//    while(theList.isEmpty() == false)
//       {
//       theList.delete();
//       theList.step();
//       theList.displayList();
//       }
    }  // end main()

}
```

Comment: To fix Find(), look at Step() to figure out how to stop.

Comment: I get the hint I need to use do-while loop? But that still won't change anything. I feel like I am missing another condition in the while statement or I need to introduce some sorts of counter, e.g. while(nItems !0) nItems--;

Comment: Actually, you don't need the counter! You can just use "current == head" as a check if you've run through the entire list.

Comment: the homework tag is currently discouraged.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: It's not clear from that thread that there's much consensus on the tag. I find it useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your "step" method:
You create a local reference called current, which initially points to head. After

```
current = current.next
```

it references the successor of head. And in the next step, it references the successor of that, and so on. But it's a local reference, so you don't change anything in the list.

What you have to do, as I deduce from your desired output, is as simple as

```
if( head != null && head.next != null )
    head = head.next
```

Next: For your find-method:
Well, from your loop condition, it's quite obvious that it will run forever if the key is not in the list, because this is your only breaking condition. You should think of a mechanism that makes it stop after you've looked at every item in the list. Hint: Look at what you've done in your version of the step() method.

To your delete-method:
The first part is (partially) okay (it has the same infinite-loop problem as your find-method). 
What you do is iterate through the list until the data of current is equal to the key. That's fine.

But now, current is a reference to the element you want to delete. But what you do is setting current.next to current.next.next, which means that you are deleting the successor of current, instead of current itself! In your loop where you search for the key, you must keep track of the predecessor, so that you can change predecessor.next to current.next, which is what you really want to do.

And then, of course, you must check if it's the head you're deleting, and if that's the case, you must set it to either the predecessor or the successor of it.

Finally, I see a problem with your insert() method! I don't see how this can produce a circular linked list, because you let the newly inserted element point to the head and make it the new head, but nothing points to it. So you only create a singly linked list? You insert a new item "before" the head ( current.next = head ) but then you should also have the former predecessor of head now point to the new item, current!

Comment: With 2 step() calls I get this result: 60 50 40 30 20 10 10 50 40 30 20 10 10 10. Are you sure the condition is correct? Iirc we don't have to worry about NULL at all in Circular Linked Lists. And right now current has never been used after I initialized Link current = head;

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. The purpose of the step method is to move the head one step further along the circle, so you basically only need head = head.next, but since your list might be empty, I'd test for head == null. Sure, you can omit the head.next == null, that's true.

Comment: Lag, you are right. But there's a bigger problem, you see those trailing 10s? They shouldn't be there, instead the "old" head should be in that place. Linked List should stay in tact: I have 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, so at each step I must have those values still there.

Comment: Just to clarify: Let's say your initial list is
10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70.
Then you call step() twice and this should make your list become
30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 10, 20. Is this correct?
In that case, I'm pretty sure that the step() method should contain only "head = head.next" and nothing else.

Comment: That's right but this is the output with just head = head.next. 1) 60 50 40 30 20 10 10 
2) 50 40 30 20 10 10 10 
3) 40 30 20 10 10 10 10 . Maybe it's my insert() method that's causing this?

Comment: Your insert method has an error as well, see my (edited) answer.